# Replacement on Reaper for garageband's virtual drummer?

Tags: drum-kits, garage-band, virtual-instrument, cockos-reaper

Recent versions of garageband have a ["virtual drummer"](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH24948) that can "follow" a midi song and provide accompaniment in one of several styles (e.g., "rock", "pop", "reggae", ..), and with a 2-dimensional high-level control ("complexity" and maybe "volume"?).  It's really simple if you want a scratch backing track.

Does Reaper (or maybe another VST-plugin-accepting system) have a replacement that works with this same high-level control?

All the drummer plugins I've seen are about the recording quality of the instrument, and have you program them with MIDI, which is a lot lower level.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what the virtual drummer does, but the new **Band-in-a-Box** 2019 has a DAW plugin (VST/AAX) that might do what you want. 
Update 11/2019: there now seems to be a VST/AU/AAX plugin version for the Mac as well, though apparently only 64 bit  https://www.pgmusic.com/bbmac.htm

Here it is demonstrated in Reaper:

Some other virtual drummer software that comes to mind, with random Youtube videos showing them in or with Reaper.

**Drumcore** (a free version shown here)

---

**Jamstix**

---

**EZ Drummer**

---

In addition to those, Steven Slate Drums aka SSD, and other drum software have drum grooves, which might help you do what you want.